# _.throttle implementation using RXJS observables

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, rxjs, throttling

I am new to Rxjs Observables and I need to implement throttling using Rxjs.

In underscore we do that with the following line -

```
_.throttle(functionName, timespan, {trailing : true/false}).
```

Kindly assist how to do that with observables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [`throttle`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/throttle.md) operator.

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(window, 'mousemove')
  .throttle(500)
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

It will throttle events such that only one event can come through during a single 500 millisecond window.

Comment: Appreciated. Just wanted a clarification. Rx.Observables.fromEvent will listen for event( like mousemove here). What If I do not want to listen for an event, I just want to throttle a function? I hope my question is valid. If not kindly assist. Like I said I want to imitate the behavior the following function.



    _.throttle(functionName, timespan, {trailing : true/false})

Comment: You can hack a solution as the other answer alluded to, but it isn't really an "Rx" solution. My question would be why does it have to be a function? What is calling that function? Usually with Rx the idea is to start with the source and build the pipeline around the whole task.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [sample](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/sample.md) operator in RxJs

Here is simple example with mousemove event on div.

```js
const source = document.getElementById('source');

Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent(source, 'mousemove')
  .sample(1000)
  .map(event => ({x: event.offsetX, y: event.offsetY}))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

```css
#source {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.1.0/rx.all.js"></script>

<div id="source"></div>
```

If you want to implement throttle using RxJS you can do that like this:

```js
function throttle(fn, delay) {
  const subject = new Rx.Subject();
  
  subject
    .sample(delay)
    .subscribe(args => fn(...args));
  
  return (...args) => subject.onNext(args);
}

const sourceBtn = document.getElementById('source');
const countSpan = document.getElementById('count');
let count = 0;

sourceBtn.addEventListener('click', throttle(() => {
  count++;
                                             
  countSpan.innerHTML = count;
}, 1000));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.1.0/rx.all.js"></script>

<button id="source" type="button">click</button> <br>
count = <span id="count"></span>
```

Comment: Appreciated. But is there any method that like fromEvent that takes another method as an input and throttle it using some other method lets say sample?

Comment: @PushkarKathuria I don't really get what you want, but I edited my answer so that you can see throttle simlar to that from underscore implement with RxJs. It fires function every second if there was click.

Comment: Does it work with only events? Apologies if it sounds dumb. But the task that I need to perform is to just throttle a function call. The same thing that this following line does :-

    _.throttle(function, timespan, {trailing : true/false})

The above line will throttle a function for a particular timespan and call it afterwards.

I hope I am able to clarify the issue?

Comment: Oh. Apologies but I am new to it. Could you please give me an example to using .throttle function?